# Why is a "classic" hash useful?

Tags: javascript, hash, hashmap, prototypejs

I've been tasked with maintaining some legacy front-end code that uses a lot of PrototypeJS. I'm getting confused about some things they use in the code. For example, [the documentation](http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/language/dollar-H/) describes this `$H` function for creating a "hash" and accessing properties on it in "the classic hash way" which appears to be a simple `obj.get('propName')`.

```
var h = $H({name: 'John', age: 26, country: 'Australia'});
// Equivalent to:
var h = new Hash({name: 'John', age: 26, country: 'Australia'});
// Can then be accessed the classic Hash way
h.get('country');
// -> 'Australia'
```

Why is this useful? I'm seeing it used all over the code I'm maintaining and finally decided I need to understand what the original intention was a little better.

Comment: they have several built-in iteration methods for hashs.

Comment: @dandavis Think you could clarify? You mean for iterating the properties like `for (var key in obj)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Prototype.JS docs](http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/language/Hash/index.html):

> Because of the nature of JavaScript, every object is in fact a hash; but `Hash` adds a number of methods that let you enumerate keys and values, iterate over key/value pairs, merge two hashes together, and much more.

So, basically it's because then you can use `keys`, `values`, `each`, `merge`, `update`, etc.

Comment: Ah, I somehow missed that. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

A "classic hash" is typically useful because it provides fast key-value pair lookup. In Computer Science terms, the algorithmic complexity is constant, or O(1). This means that you can immediately get the value for any of the keys in the hash. In the example hash, the keys are: name, age, country

So you can quickly get the name (John) by calling h.get('name'), you can quickly get his age (26) by calling h.get('age'), and you can quickly get his country (Australia) by calling h.get('country').

Compare this to storing this data in a list that you have to iterate through to find the values of name, age, and country.